# How to connect GKE with external database which is running on different project's VM?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have GKE with public nodes(nodes having its external IP), I want to connect with the MySql database which is running inside a VM in a different project. I tried to connect with the load balancer but it's getting timed out. I tried with cloud NAT, still I cannot make the connection.

However, I am able to connect if I whitelist the exact external IP of the node where the pod is running (from where I want to connect with the database). But I cannot add all the node external IPs to the firewall since it has a lot of nodes.

What is the way to create single external IP which I can use to whitelist so I can make connection to the VM from Public GKE Cluster?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the **NAT gateway** in front of all the VMs or nodes running your GKE cluster.

So all the outgoing traffic goes from a single **egress** point.

You can check : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/latest/examples/gke-nat-gateway

you can directly apply it and your GKE will be running behind the NAT and all traffic from the pod will be going out from the single point.

to verify **egress** is working or not

you can `exec` into the pod and send `curl ifconfig.me` request in response you get your external IP.

Try from the pods scheduled on **different nodes**.

Once everything is set you can **whitelist** the **NAT IP** in the database.